# Nullable boolean check in WHERE clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

The following query yields an error

```
select 1 where case null when null then true when true then true else false end

ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = boolean
```

What is the correct way to perform a nullable boolean value check in the WHERE clause?

**Udate**

Suprisingly this one works fine

```
create table d (id serial, v boolean);
insert into d(v) values(null),(true),(false);
select id from d where case v when null then true when v then true else true end;

 id
----
  1
  2
  3
(3 rows)
```

PS: actually this does not work either because the null value is casted to boolean and hence `else` is triggered instead of `when null`.

Comment: The whole expression makes no sense to me. What is the actual underlying problem you are trying to solve with that? If you want to treat `null` as `true` why not simply use `where v or v is null`?

Comment: I need to construct the query from within nodejs code with the value defined explisitly as null/true/false as shown in the original example.

Comment: `where $1 is null or $1`? with `$1` being the parameter. Or better: only append the condition if the parameter is not null

Comment: Laurenz Albe's solution resolves the `case` approach but your alternative solution suits my case better. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error stems from the fact that PostgreSQL decides on the data type for the NULL *without* considering the `WHEN` clauses. Lacking other information, it goes for `text`. You can prevent that with an explicit type cast to `boolean`.

But your real problem is different. Look at this:

```
SELECT CASE NULL::boolean
           WHEN NULL THEN 'is null'
           WHEN TRUE THEN 'is true'
           ELSE 'is false'
       END;

   case   
══════════
 is false
(1 row)
```

The problem here is that if first `WHEN` will evaluate `NULL = NULL`, which results in `NULL` and not in `TRUE`.

Either treat nullness in the `ELSE` branch:

```
CASE NULL::boolean
   WHEN TRUE THEN 'is true'
   WHEN FALSE THEN 'is false'
   ELSE 'is null'
END
```

or use

```
CASE
   WHEN NULL IS NULL THEN 'is null'
   WHEN NULL IS TRUE THEN 'is true'
   WHEN NULL IS FALSE THEN 'is false'
END
```

Comment: if you cast null to boolean then `when null` condition will never trigger

Comment: That's what I am saying.

Comment: so the solution is to use "case when null is null.." instead of "case null when null".

Comment: Right. Or use the `ELSE` branch, as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast that first null to a boolean.  Postgres is casting it to text, which results in your error.

```
select 1 where case null::boolean when null then true when true then true else false end;
```

That said, it might be easier to use `DISTINCT FROM` or `NOT DISTINCT FROM` depending on your actual use case.

Comment: In addition to `DISTINCT FROM`, booleans have their own set of null-aware [comparison operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE); this specific case looks like it boils down to `NULL IS NOT FALSE`

Comment: if you cast null to boolean then `when null` condition will never trigger

Comment: @yaugenka It solves the ERROR you were getting, but it's unclear to me what you behavior you are actually looking for.  Some sample data and expected results would be useful.